# How to check radio button status on UI (whether it is enabled or disabled)- robot framework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

How to check whether a radio button status (is enabled or disabled). Is there any selenium2 keyword for this? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In case you mearly want to test if a radio button has a certain value set, then you should use 1 `Radio Button Should be Set To` [Documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Radio%20Button%20Should%20Be%20Set%20To)

In case you have logic that enables an entire radio button group, and want to test for that then the standard keyword `Element Should be Enabled` is more appropriate. [Documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Element%20Should%20Be%20Enabled)